# GRPC Load Balancing with Envoy

Tags: go, google-kubernetes-engine, grpc, istio, envoyproxy

Might be a dumb question (apologies)....

I currently have a microservice application written in GO and using GRPC for all service to service communication.   I am currently using client side load balancing written in GRPC and would like to switch over to a proxy method (istio with envoy).

I can easily enable istio and sidecar injection.   What I am confused on is how I get envoy to RoundRobin across all the services.   Do I need to do anything client side?  Will envoy automatically see the services as they scale?  Seems almost too good to be true that I just need to enable sidecar injection and everything should work like magic.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a decent [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/istio-grpc-loadbalancing-with-gcp-internal-loadbalancer-ilb-1b058b517640) describing how to setup Istio gRPC Loadbalancing.

There a two cases:

```
client_grpc_app (on GCEVM) --> (GCP ILB) --> Istio --> Service
client_grpc_app (external) --> (GCP ExternalLB) --> Istio --> Service
```

Hope you find it helpful

Comment: Is the article not specific to GCP? How can we make it work in vanilla k8s platform?